# How do I get the current cell in a table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cells

So I'm trying to create a live-updating table using HTML and jQuery. Each row contains expenses, and each cell in the row has a specific formula attached to it. If the user edits any of the cells in a row, then the others in that row will reflect the change.

Example:

```
[Cell 1] [Cell 2] [Cell 3]

[Cell 1] = 1;
[Cell 2] = [Cell 1] * 2
[Cell 3] = [Cell 1] * 12
```

I'd love it if the table updated on blur or on keyup, but I don't know how to get the current cell, and update the other cells in that particular row. Basically, I would have a check to see WHICH cell in the row was edited, and update the others accordingly.

```
if(cell1 was updated) { update cell2, cell3 }

else if(cell2 was updated) { update cell1, cell3 }

else if(cell3 was updated) { update cell1, cell2 }
```

I tried this to grab the ID of the current cell, and use that to grab the value of another cell in that row. Didn't work:

```
var id;

$(".moneyTable input").focus(function () {
             id = this;
        });

$('.moneyTable input').blur(function() {
            calculateRow(id);
        });

function calculateRow(id) {
        var a = $(id).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();
        alert(a);
    }
```

Comment: How did u attach a formula with a particular cell in row ?
Can u create any [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for example ?

Comment: I haven't done that part yet. I was just going to get the value of the cell the user JUST updated and calculate the others from that one. It's simple multiplication math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I don't know how to get the current cell, and update the other cells in that particular row"*

When your event handler is called `this` will be a reference to the element in question, so from there you can figure out which row it belongs to:

```
$('.moneyTable input').blur(function() {
    var $thisInput = $(this),
        $thisTD = $thisInput.parent(), // or $thisInput.closest("td")
        $thisTR = $thisInput.closest("tr"),
        $otherCells = $thisTR.find("input").not(this); // and so forth
});
```

As far as checking whether the clicked cell was cell 1, 2 or 3, there are a few ways to do it. One would be give them classes `class="cell1"` and so forth, then do:

```
if($thisInput.hasClass("cell1")) {
    // do something
```

Or check the `.index()` of the parent td within the row:

```
if($thisTD.index() === 1) {
    // second cell (zero-based indexes)
```

Comment: Will this be able to identify the cell that was just "blurred", or will it lose this reference?

Comment: It will be the one just blurred. Definitely. That's the point of the blur event...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is exel like plugin that would let your table work like spreadsheet

try this plugin I think this is what you want

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/calculation/calculation.plugin.htm